# Why does the snippet in my notifications contain a string that doesn’t appear in the post?

Tags: support

In my notifications it shows the first few words of the subject answer. Here the answer seems to begin with the word “assuming”.

Then I open the (never edited) answer, and it doesn’t contain that word anywhere within.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a small period of grace (for want of a better word) after posting, when the user's edit doesn't appear in the timeline.

My best guess is Jen's original reply began with "assuming the tenancy..." which triggered a notification with that wording, before Jen (presumably) edited it in that grace period.